# Code analysis error CS8019 on auto-generated file in Temp folder

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis, fxcop

I recently enabled Code Analysis for a couple of projects in Visual Studio 2015 solution. It was all working fine, but when I opened the solution on another computer I started getting this code analysis error:

> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs(3,1,3,25):
>   error CS8019: Unnecessary using directive.

I opened this file manually and saw that it indeed had 2 using directives at the top. Then I checked this file on my 1st computer, the usings were not present there, and its modification date was the same day I added code analysis initially.

The main question is: how do I get rid of this error and what is its cause?

I also wonder why code analysis checks this file at all (I have checked the option "Suppress results from auto-generated code") and why this file wasn't modified on the 2nd computer.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? This problem still persist even in VS2017 era